# JavaScript builtin find() function not working with angularjs 1.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am trying to use Angularjs and I'm not very good at it. I'm trying to find something from the madeUpCards[] array. using the find() function of javascript.
I am not entirely sure, I think it's not working when I use it with Angularjs.
here is the my Code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h3>{{getCardById('14')}}</h3>
</body>
```

array here:

```
    $scope.madeUpCards = [
     {
        "id": "23",
        "name": "The brain",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Portal dead",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Holiday",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "warded",
        "closed": true,
    },
];
```

javascript :

```
const app = /**
* myApp Module
*
* Description
*/
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.getCardById = function(id) {
        this.id = id
        let foundCard = $scope.madeUpCards.find(function(card, index){
            return card.id == this.id
        });
    return foundCard.name;
    }

}]);
```

in the console this appears:

```
 angular.js:15536 TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
  at ChildScope.$scope.getCardById ((index):49)
  at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:16387), <anonymous>:4:234)
  at expressionInputWatch (angular.js:17398)
  at Scope.$digest (angular.js:19095)
  at Scope.$apply (angular.js:19463)
  at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1945)
  at Object.invoke (angular.js:5122)
  at doBootstrap (angular.js:1943)
  at bootstrap (angular.js:1963)
  at angularInit (angular.js:1848)
```

pleas help me how to fix this, or atleast tell me what's wrong.

Comment: what is `Cards` here passed through HTML `getCardById(Cards, '14')`?

Comment: what is your expected output for your foundCard?

Comment: the (Cards, '14') is the $scope.madeUpCard array, I would like to get the card as object with id of 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `const madeUpCards` to `$scope.Cards` in your controller, and instead of passing in `Cards`, just use `<h3>{{ getCardById('14') }}</h3>`

Then in your controller, use `$scope.Cards`.  i.e.
In the controller:

```
$scope.Cards = [
     {
        "id": "23",
        "name": "The brain",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Portal dead",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Holiday",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "warded",
        "closed": true,
    },
];

...

$scope.getCardById = function(id) {
    let foundCard = $scope.Cards.find(function(card, index){
        return card.id == this.id
    });
    return foundCard.name;
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h3>{{ getCardById('14') }}</h3>
</body>
```

Now you could still pass in Cards to `getCardById`, but it's already accessible in your controller so it would be pointless.

---

AngularJS will only bind elements to the DOM that are defined on the scope.

You created `Cards` as a local variable in the controller, but not part of the scope.  So in the HTML when you pass `Cards` into a function, its undefined (not part of the scope).

This passes undefined into your controller, and then you attempt to call `find` on undefined, hence your error.

Comment: should I include $scope.Cards inside the controller?

Comment: @Vanz yes, I would, especially if it's a constant or returned from the server.

Comment: @Vanz `getCardById` is returning an object, so you would need to `return foundCard.Name` if you want to display the name of the card in the header.  If it's still blank then, debug the call to `getCardById` and make sure you're finding a card

Comment: when I include return foundCard.name error appears. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: @Venz so that means that `foundCard` is undefined.  Which means your `find` function cannot find a card with Id = 14 (in this example).  Could you paste your new find function?  It's hard for me to say for sure without seeing it.

Comment: I have done, editing it. what do you see wrong? super thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure thing - I'm on my way into work, so it'll be 20min before I can look for sure, but try just using `id` instead of `this.id`.  That seems strange to me.

Comment: I remove the this.id = id, and then "card.id == id" it works, Big thanks!!!. but what's the difference of using "this.id" and directly "id"? it works and I dont know how. thanks again

Comment: @Venz `this` keyword is used for when you want properties on an object (has nothing to do with angular really).  Because you're simply in a function, `this` really has no meaning.  It's possible that `this.id` is not a property so even though you write `this.id = id` it leaves `this.id` as undefined.  In your case there's no real reason to use `this.id` because you just want the value from the view.  Great I'm glad its working!

Answer (score 0):

Cards is undefined, try that

```
<h3>{{ getCardById([
     {
        "id": "23",
        "name": "The brain",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Portal dead",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Holiday",
        "closed": true,
    },
     {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "warded",
        "closed": true,
    },
], '14') }}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>{{ getCardById(Cards, '14') }}</h3>
```

According to this snippet, the variable `Cards` should be binded to `$scope`.

So, define a `$scope.Cards` at the initial part of the controller as below:

```
const app = /**
* myApp Module
*
* Description
*/
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.Cards = [
        {
            "id": "23",
            "name": "The brain",
            "closed": true,
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Portal dead",
            "closed": true,
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "name": "Holiday",
            "closed": true,
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "name": "warded",
            "closed": true,
        },
    ];

    $scope.getCardById = function(cards, id) {
        this.cards = cards
        this.id = id
        let foundCard = this.cards.find(function(card, index){
            return card.id == this.id
        });
        return foundCard;
    };

}]);
```

Happy coding.